# How do I increment cell value by 1 in excel using AppleScript?

Tags: excel, applescript

This should be simple but I'm probably not approaching it the right way. I simply want to increase the value of cell "C7" from 4 to 5. This is how I imagine it working. Any suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
    get value of cell "C7"
    set value of cell "C7" to current value +1
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In VBA and in Applescript, Excel needs to know the workbook and the sheet to work on. Assuming your workbook and sheet, where you want to change the cell, are the activated ones, then :

```
tell application "Microsoft Excel"
tell active workbook to tell active sheet to set value of cell "C7" to (value of cell "C7") + 1
end tell
```